# Equation numbering with the same number of digits?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, numbering, align

I'm writing a document with more than 10 equations per section. The ams align environment is numbering them as:

```
1.1, 1.2, ..., 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, ...
```

Instead I would like the equations to be numbered as:

```
1.01, 1.02, ..., 1.09, 1.10, 1.11, ...
```

How would I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you provide a `MWE`, it will helps us to help you in a better way....

Comment: `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\ifnum\value{equation}<10 
0\fi\number\value{equation}}`

Comment: Thankyou, that works perfectly! Sorry I didn't provide a MWE, I thought it'd be a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is due to @user121799; that user is retiring from the site and no longer providing full answers, so I am "rescuing" their correct answer.

To add leading zeros to an equation number so that all equation numbers are the same length, redefine `\theequation` as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation{%
  \arabic{section}.%
  \ifnum\value{equation}<10 0\fi
  \number\value{equation}}
```